# Sql Server: How to get aggregate statistics across fields

Tags: sql-server

Not sure if the title is phrased correctly here...

But in any case, for simplicity's sake, I have a table with three fields like below:

```
USER_ID         Number_Of_Apples         Number_Of_Pears
ABC1                    1                     NULL
ABC2                    1                     NULL
ABC3                   NULL                    5
ABC4                    1                     12
```

I want to know if there's a way to do a 'distinct' query of sorts that will give me the different levels of data per field. So in the example above, I want to see something like:

```
USER_ID      Number_OF_Apples      Number_OF_Pears
   4                2                     3
```

2 is returned for Number_Of_Apples b/c we only see 2 possible values in our dataset.

I'm wondering if there's an elegant way of doing this if you had 100 fields or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181759/sql-server-look-for-nulls-across-all-columns) you can count distinct with a coalesce to make sure you count the nulls:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(COALESCE([USER_ID], 'nullitem'))) [USER_ID],
       COUNT(DISTINCT(COALESCE([Number_Of_Apples], 'nullitem'))) [Number_Of_Apples],
       COUNT(DISTINCT(COALESCE([Number_Of_Pears], 'nullitem'))) [Number_Of_Pears]
FROM mytable
```

Just add whatever items you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID)
        FROM mytable) AS USER_ID,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                                 WHEN Number_Of_Apples IS NULL THEN -1  
                                 ELSE Number_Of_Apples
                              END) 
        FROM mytable)   AS Number_Of_Apples                       , 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                                 WHEN Number_Of_Pears IS NULL THEN -1  
                                 ELSE Number_Of_Pears
                              END) AS Number_Of_Pears
        FROM mytable) AS Number_Of_Pears
```

The above query uses a `CASE` expression so as to handle `NULL` values for `Number_Of_Apples` and `Number_Of_Pears` columns.  I've made the assumption that `-1` is not a possible value for these two columns.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86cfc/1)